# Fast SIMD for cumulative product of complex doubles

Tags: c, simd, complex-numbers, avx

I need to compute the cumulative product of an array of complex numbers as quickly as possible.  In C this would be:

```
#include <complex.h>
complex double cumprod(complex double a[], complex double s[], int n) {
    complex double prod = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        prod *= a[i];
        s[i] = prod;
    }
    return prod;
}
```

In my case `30 <  n < 50`.

When compiled with `-O3 -march=core-avx2 -ffast-math` using gcc this gives:

```
cumprod:
        test    edx, edx
        jle     .L4
        sub     edx, 1
        lea     rax, [rdi+8]
        vxorpd  xmm1, xmm1, xmm1
        add     rsi, 8
        sal     rdx, 4
        vmovsd  xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        lea     rdx, [rdi+24+rdx]
.L3:
        vmovsd  xmm2, QWORD PTR [rax]
        vmovsd  xmm3, QWORD PTR [rax-8]
        add     rax, 16
        add     rsi, 16
        vmulsd  xmm4, xmm2, xmm0
        vmulsd  xmm2, xmm2, xmm1
        vfmadd132sd     xmm1, xmm4, xmm3
        vfmsub132sd     xmm0, xmm2, xmm3
        vmovsd  QWORD PTR [rsi-16], xmm1
        vmovsd  QWORD PTR [rsi-24], xmm0
        cmp     rdx, rax
        jne     .L3
        ret
.L4:
        vxorpd  xmm1, xmm1, xmm1
        vmovsd  xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        ret
```

Sadly it seems gcc can't vectorize this at all itself.

> Is it possible to speed this up using AVX SIMD instructions? Alternatively, is there any other way to speed up this code?

For comparison, here is what [ICC does](https://godbolt.org/g/Za7ucp).

Comment: some simple examples https://ds9a.nl/gcc-simd/example.html

Comment: Consider using clang, which does [a half-decent job of vectorizing the above](https://godbolt.org/g/2EcEcs) ?

Comment: @PaulR Shouldn't it be using the ymm registers at least?

Comment: Yes, that's why I said half-decent. ;-)

Comment: What you're asking for is essentially a [Parallel-Prefix Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum#Parallel_algorithm) - but with multiplication instead of addition. IMO, asking the compiler to recognize that pattern and generate a SIMD implementation of a Parallel-Prefix Sum is like asking the compiler to turn a bubble sort into a quick sort. I don't see that happening any time soon. They can do stuff like reductions, but a prefix sum is much more complicated.

Comment: @Mysticial I completely agree. I am asking for help for how to do either almost all or all of it by hand.  The added complication is the complex number multiplication which needs some cleverness to do well using AVX.

Comment: TBH, you're not gonna gain much with only AVX. While a prefix sum reduces that *latency* to obtain the result from `O(N)` down to `O(log(N))` assuming infinite processors, it increases the amount of total work from `O(N)` to `O(N*log(N))`. And with a vector size of only 4 (or 2 for complex double), you're pretty far removed from being able to overcome the factor of `log(N)` overhead.

Comment: @Mysticial That's very interesting. I would still really like to understand what the optimal assembly is.  gcc, clang and icc give very different offerings for the C code in the question and in general C compilers don't handle the complex type well.

Comment: Fundamentally, a prefix sum is just a recursion. You split the data in half. Do a prefix sum on both sides. Then take the last element of the bottom half and add it to all the elements in the top half. The two prefix-sums at the beginning are independent and can be done in parallel. And the final add-back is also purely parallelizable/vectorizable. But the amount of shuffling you'll need to exploit the former is probably going to outweigh the cost. Even with AVX512 on real floats (16/vector), I can't say if it'll be large enough to be worthwhile.

Comment: @eleanora Are your recent questions about complex SIMD operations out of couriosity, or are they really a critical path in your application? Do you have any information on how `a[]` is generated (maybe it's possible to calculate the cummulative product in another way)? Alternatively, how is the cumprod used afterwards? And if neither of that helps, would computing 4 (or more) cumulative products (of different same-sized `a[]`) be an option?

Comment: @PaulR It seems like clang 'just' has an optimization for a single complex multiplication inside sse registers. But as Mystical pointed out, it seems unlikely that a compiler could do more here automatically ...

Comment: @chtz It will be used as part of another algorithm. I will add that to the question later on.  However, see my update that ICC can do something a little cleverer it seems.

Comment: @chtz It's a bit odd about clang, If you just remove the  `s[i] = prod;` line it's optimization for complex multiplication seems to disappear https://godbolt.org/g/B27ftV . I may be reading the assembly incorrectly of course.